# Using Count to generate another field

Tags: mysql, count, case

i have a mysql query and i want to use the result of a count to generate another field.

This is what i was thinking:

```
  SELECT COUNT(FIELD) AS Q,
    CASE 
      WHEN Q > 1 THEN 'MORE THAN 1' ELSE 'LESS OR EQUAL'
    END FIELD_CODIFIED
  FROM TABLE
```

Is that possible?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But i thik you have to write

`SELECT COUNT(FIELD) AS Q,
    CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(FIELD) > 1 THEN 'MORE THAN 1' ELSE 'LESS OR EQUAL'
    END FIELD_CODIFIED
  FROM TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
When I post the question, i found the solution:

```
SELECT IF (COUNT(FIELD)>1,'MORE THAN 1','LESS OR EQUAL') AS FIELD_CODIFIED FROM TABLE
```